# Border Radius not working in safari

Tags: css, safari

I have a page with a google maps in it, now I'm trying to make a border radius on it. This is working in browsers like Chrome and Firefox but not working on safari.

You can find the page here: [clients.steven-dejong.nl/amano/#contact](http://clients.steven-dejong.nl/amano/#contact)

EDIT:
It's working with the address block and if I add -webkit-border-radius and -moz-border-radius it makes no sense.

The only part where my border radius isn't working is the google maps container

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Border Radius to Google Map in Safari

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);

-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Use this snippet to both the map iframe and its parent div

Comment: Also you should use all prefixes while adding border radius. Like -webkite-border-radius: value;

Comment: Also visit this URL: https://itskamalkumarblog.wordpress.com/2015/12/04/border-radius-to-google-map-in-safari-not-working/ for further reference and any issue, drop your message here

Answer (score 0):

Use the -webkit prefix and do something like below:

```
 /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Adjust as needed */
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work in all browsers:

```
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
```

Comment: safari support normal border-radius, I have the latest version on OS X Yosemite. It works on every element. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) [screenshot](http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=21193)